# When extending Magento's core classes, what XML structure do I need to alter for my changes to take effect?

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am working with a Magento 1.3 (Community Edition) install and I am trying to extend the functionality of one of the core classes. I changed the core file directly on a development server, and got the functionality working there. Now, [following Alan Storm's advice](http://alanstorm.com/magento_upgrade_rewrite_override), I'm reverting the core files back to stock and implementing my changes in the `/app/code/local` tree. I've been reading Alan Storm's page and [a guide from Josh Pratt](http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/), but I can't quite figure out how to apply those examples to my case.

The core of the question is - how much of the skeleton of a full-on Magento module do I need to implement in order to extend/monkey-patch core classes?

- Do I need to create my own namespace?
- When I name classes, which underscores should I expect to be syntactically significant?
- When I write the XML, which tags correspond to the class hierarchy and which don't?
- What other parts of the code will need to be changed to take advantage of my changes, if any?

Basically I'd like to not cargo-cult this.

The particulars of my scenario: I'm trying to alter the product review functionality of Magento. The code for this functionality lives in `/app/code/core/Mage/Review/`. I'm adding an additional step to the server-side validation when new reviews are submitted (our store is having a spam issue, so I'm adding an extra form field, hiding it from humans with CSS, and throwing out reviews that fill in that form field; I'm doing it this way because CAPTCHAs are a sub-optimal UI choice). I added code to `/app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php`'s Mage_Review_ProductController->postAction() method and to `/app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Review.php`'s Mage_Review_Model_Review->validate() method.

I then isolated the added code, put it into `/app/code/local/Mage/Review/controllers/ProductController.php` and `/app/code/local/Mage/Review/Model/Review.php`, used the "class My_Review_Foo extends Mage_Review_Foo" and "parent::method" recommendations from Alan Storm's tutorials. That, predictably, broke the product pages. So I'm working on `/app/code/local/Mage/Review/etc/config.xml` and trying to figure out how to get Magento to use my classes to *extend* the core classes. Unfortunately, I can't tell what the underlying logic to the XML is, so I can't figure out how to construct the right XML to tell Magento - "use my classes instead of the core classes, whenever you would use the core classes."

It looks like pretty much any change to the core classes ends up needing the full pomp and circumstance of a Magento plugin. Is that correct? How much do I actually need to do to shim my changes in, and what's the logic behind doing it that way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Magento is all about configuration. The most basic functional module out there will contain nothing but configuration XML which adds to or overrides existing configuration XML. That said, most development needs require implementing configuration which adds discrete new functionality to the system and/or alters existing functionality.

There are two ways to rewrite block (which equate to the "view" in MVC), helper, and model classes, and these work either because of include path order (set in the `Mage` hub class and used by `Varien_Autoload`), or - more appropriately - via configuration-based rewrites, which are evaluated in `Mage_Core_Model_Config::getGroupedClassName()` method. See below for rewrite instructions based on rewriting `Mage_Review_Model_Review`.

By design (as a security feature) neither of these approaches works for controllers; ultimately the controller class definitions are protected from being autoloaded. What follows then is an explanation on how to rewrite action controller classes by non-deprecated means (1.3.0 to 1.6.1.1 at this time). *Note that prior to Magento CE 1.3.0, the way to rewrite functionality in action controller classes was via configuration XML.*

To rewrite controller definitions one must understand how controller classes are invoked in Magento, and this occurs through the router classes. Magento core has four router classes. Routers sit between the FrontController class (`Mage_Core_Controller_Front`), and they are responsible for matching the request and altering the response body. The FrontController will loop through each class, and each class will be evaluated to determine whether it should handle the current request. Often this is a matter of configuration + filepath convention. Essentially, Magento matches a frontname to an initial directory and then matches the rest of the request to a path and file under that directory. For example, a product page's literal path in the application may be http://demo.magentocommerce.com/review/product/list/id/51/. In this URL structure, **review** is the *frontName* (a node from the configuration), and it is mapped to `app/code/core/Mage/Review/controllers/`. From there, **product** maps to a path & filename under that directory, i.e. `ProductController.php`, and from there the resolved class is checked for a **list***Action* method. See? review + product + list are the frontName, controller class path, and method "resolution params". Anything after that is passed as a request param (e.g. *id=51*).

Since CE 1.3.0 it is possible to simply add one's action controller class to a list of directories in which the router will check for resolvable paths (see `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard::collectRoutes()` for more info). How this works is typical Magento: through config XML! Incidentally, this technique works both for adding new controller class paths as well as for controller rewrites.

A controller rewrite module will need at least three files:

- a module declaration file (a file ending in `.xml` under the `app/etc/modules/` directory)
- a `config.xml` in the module's `etc` directory
- a controller file *with the same path resolution as the class which is being rewritten*. In the case of a class path of "product" from the above example, the file must be named `ProductController.php` and be located at the top of the controllers directory which is being added, else it will not match the class resolution params. Also, the action being rewritten must match the original as well for the same reason.

The declaration file will contain the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Example_Extension>
            <active>true</true>
            <codePool>local</codePool> <!-- or community -->
        </Example_Extension>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Based on the above `<Example_Extension>` and `<codePool>` nodes, the application will attempt to load `app/code/local/Example/Extension/etc/config.xml`. In this file, if one were seeking to rewrite the Review module's ProductController class, one would need the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <review>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <some_unique_node before="Mage_Review">Example_Extension</some_unique_node>
                        <!--
                            This will map to the controllers directory under the
                            app/code/local/Example/Extension/ directory. Had this
                            value been "Example_Extension_Rewrites", the mapping
                            would be to the
                            app/code/local/Example/Extension/controllers/Rewrites/
                            directory. That is just how controller class paths are
                            evaluated: with a "controllers" directory after two levels
                            of folders.
                        -->
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </review>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Because of the `before="Mage_Review"` attribute, the Example_Extension module's controllers directory will be added ahead of the core Review module controller directory. Therefore, if the controller and action resolution params match in the Example_Extension module, its class will be used. If not, the default scenario will play out.

Finally, the remaining file to make is the action controller class itself. If the intention is to inherit from core functionality, then it makes sense to extend from the core class. However, in order for the PHP to load the definition for the core class, the core class has to be referenced directly as there's no way for PHP to find the definition via the autoloader as mentioned. This means adding a `require_once` before the rewritten class definition.

```
<?php

require_once 'Mage'.DS.'Review'.DS.'controllers'.DS.'ProductController.php';

class Example_Extension_ProductController extends Mage_Review_ProductController
{
    //rewritten and/or new method(s)
}
```

Just as is the case with block, helper, and model classes in Magento, the application expects classes to have a specific name which will relate to their location in the filesystem.

Regarding model (and block and helper) class rewrites: one need only add the necessary configuration XML and class definition. Given the examples here, a rewrite of `Mage_Review_Model_Review` would require an addition to the Example_Extension's config.xml:

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <global>
        <models>
            <review>
                <rewrite>
                    <review>Example_Extension_Model_Review</review>
                </rewrite>
            </review>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Based on this, `Mage::getModel('review/review')` (or `Mage::getSingleton('review/review')`) will internally map to the classname given in the `<rewrite>` node and will return the rewritten class instance. Due to how the autoloader works (see `Varien_Autoload` at `lib/Varien/Autoload.php`), that class definition will need to be located at `Example/Extension/Model/Review.php` and should be under the codePool specified in the Example_Extension's declaration file.

Hope this helps. For further information, feel free to look into other posts on SO as well as Magento U.

Comment: That was an impressively thorough answer. Thank you! That kind of answer is great evangelism for Magento. :)